# ag-grid resetRowHeights not working

Tags: ag-grid

I am new to ag-grid and have run into some issues that I can't seem to find solution of. I hope people here will able to help. So here we go.

ag-grid version: community edition

java script framework: vue js

Background:

I got JSON data and its structure is as follows

```
project 
  project_number
  applicants:
    First_name
    Last_name
```

Now a project can multiple applicants. In ag-grid I have multiple column groups such that ag-grid looks like

```
Project               Applicants
Project_Number        Total | First_Name | Last_Name
```

Above, Total column only gets displayed when column group is closed and it shows the number of applicants for a project.

For applicants I have got cell Rendered which shows values depending upon the column. For total it display the length of an array i.e. number of applicants and for first_name and last_name it shows concated values of full_name in an array and does the same the thing for last_name.

Code:

```
colDef= [{
           headerName: 'Project_Name',
           field: 'Project_Name'
         },
         {
           headerName: 'Applicants',
           marryChildren: true,
           children: [{
                 headerName: 'Total',
                 columnGroupShow: 'closed',
                 cellRenderer: fnCellRenderer,
                 autoHeight: true
            },{
                 headerName: 'First_name',
                 columnGroupShow: 'open',
                 cellRenderer: fnCellRenderer,
                 autoHeight: true
            },
            {
                 headerName: 'Last_Name',
                 columnGroupShow: 'open',
                 cellRenderer: fnCellRenderer,
                 autoHeight: true
            }]

        }]

 fnCellRenderer = function(params){

     let colDef = params.colDef;
     let fieldName = colDef['field'];
     let cellValue = params.value;

     if(fieldName === 'Total'){
           return `<span ><u>${cellValue.length}</u></span>`;

      }else if (cellValue.length){

         let templateString = '';
         for(let value of cellValue){
             let fieldValue = value[fieldName];
             if(fieldValue){
                  templateString = templateString + fieldValue + '<br/>';
               }                    
             }    

          return templateString

         }else{
             return '';
         }
}
```

rowData: [{
               project_number: '1',
               applicants:[{
                             first_name: 'sam',
                             last_name: 'dam'
                           },{
                             first_name: 'sam',
                             last_name: 'dam'
                           },{
                             first_name: 'sam',
                             last_name: 'dam'
                           },{
                             first_name: 'sam',
                             last_name: 'dam'
                           },{
                             first_name: 'sam',
                             last_name: 'dam'
                           },{
                             first_name: 'sam',
                             last_name: 'dam'
                           },{
                             first_name: 'sam',
                             last_name: 'dam'
                           },{
                             first_name: 'sam',
                             last_name: 'dam'
                           },{
                             first_name: 'sam',
                             last_name: 'dam'
                           },{
                             first_name: 'sam',
                             last_name: 'dam'
                           },{
                             first_name: 'sam',
                             last_name: 'dam'
                           }]
             }]

Problem statement:

1) How do I center cell content. I can get center horizontally working but I can't get vertically working.

2) The row height of Total column is quite big even when column group is close. It row height seems to equal as if column group is open. What I want is that row height should adjust when column group is open.

I tried api.resetRowHeights() in column group open and close event handler but it doesn't seems to be working. Code and image below.

```
 <ag-grid-vue class="ag-theme-material grid"
                    :gridOptions="gridOptions"
                    v-bind:rowData="rowData"
                    enableSorting="true"
                    enableFilter="true"
                    enableColResize="true"
                    :columnGroupOpened="columnGroupOpened">
   </ag-grid-vue> 

   columnGroupOpened: function(params){
      this.gridOptions.api.resetRowHeights();
   }
```

[image]
[image]

Please guide.

Regards,
Ajay

Answer (score 0):

From your picture, it seems that you used a string for height. And ag-grid will calculate height of each like this if you set height to "40": row 1 "40", row 2 "4040", row 3 "404040"...

Make a parseInt before.

Hope to help you.